# Windows equivalent to sync()

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I do most of my programming on embedded processors, or on linux. When i need to sync data to my persistant store, i usually use the sync(2) system call. Is there an equivelent for Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [FlushFileBuffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364439%28VS.85%29.aspx), but you need a handle to the file you need flushed.

Comment: It's not exactly what i asked for, but it is what I needed! thanks!

Answer (score 4):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364439(VS.85).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/EjectMediaByLetter.aspx

FlushFileBuffers with a handle to a volume. You have to do this for every volume :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using posix file functions (fopen() etc.), you can use _flushall:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9xk9ehd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/066/Q66052/

When you initially open your file using fopen, include the "c" mode option as the LAST OPTION:

```
fopen( path, "wc") // w - write mode, c - allow immediate commit to disk
```

Then when you want to force a flush to disk, call

```
_flushall()
```

We made this call before calling

```
fclose()
```

Note that this approach does NOT required Administrative rights, which `FlushFileBuffers` *does* require.

From that above site:

*"Microsoft C/C++ version 7.0 introduces the "c" mode option for the fopen()
function. When an application opens a file and specifies the "c" mode, the
run-time library writes the contents of the file buffer to disk when the
application calls the fflush() or _flushall() function. "*